# Complex analysis exercise - boundary points of nonconstant analytic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

The exercise has two parts:
a) Suppose $f$ is nonconstant and analytic on $S$ and $f(S)=T$. Show that if $f(z)$ is a boundary point of $T$, $z$ is a boundary point of $S$.
b) Let $f(z)=z^2$ on the set $S$ which is the union of the semi-discs $S_1=\{ z:|z|\leq 2; Re \ z\leq 0\}$ and $S_2 = \{z:|z|\leq 1; Re \ z \geq 0\}$. Show that there are points $z$ on the boundary of $S$ for which $f(z)$ is an interior point of $f(S)$.

So in part $(a)$ I suppose I have to use the Open Mapping Theorem which says that the image of an open set under a nonconstant analytic mapping is an open set, but I don't understand how I can apply it here.

In part $(b)$ my book says that $T=f(S)$ is $\overline{D(0;4)}$, why is this true? I can see that **if** this is true **then** the points $\{ z: |z|=1, Re \ z \geq 0\}$ and $\{ iy: 1<y<2 \ or \ -2<y<-1\}$ are mapped into the interior of $T$.

I hope my questions make sense. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Pretty sure the first is a consequence of the maximum modulus principle.. The maximum is attained on the boundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If $z$ is an interior point of $S$, then $f$ maps a small open set containing $z$ onto a small open set containing $f(z)$. Hence $f(z)$ can't be a boundary point of $T$. (Every open neighbourhood of a boundary point intersects the complement.)

b) $f$ maps $S_1$ onto $\overline{D(0;4)}$. If $z \in S_1$, we can write $z = re^{it}$ with $0 \le r \le 2$ and $\pi/2 \le t \le 3\pi/2$ (and all of these values of $r$ and $t$ occur), so $f(z) = z^2 = r^2e^{2it}$, and $0 \le r^2 \le 4$ and $\pi \le t \le 3\pi$, so we cover all of $\overline{D(0;4)}$. Also $f$ maps $S_2$ onto the closed unit disc (with the same reasoning). Hence $f(S_1 \cup S_2) = \overline{D(0;4)}$.

Comment: ..@mrf what  is  $D(0;4) ?$